# Read first N lines using readlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, readlines

My python code goes like this

```
with open('file.txt') as w:
    k = np.asarray(w.readlines(),np.float)
```

But when I do this k is an array with all lines read from file.txt

I am trying to figure to read only the first `n` lines and store `k` using  `np.asarray` How to edit this code with `n`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `readlines()[:n]`?

Comment: Yea it worked  thanks man! Silly me

Comment: Warning `[:n]` won't work for large files (file must be copied into memory). The second method(s) are preferred

Comment: New versions of `np.genfromtxt` take a `max_rows` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice
with open("file.txt") as myfile:
    k = list(islice(myfile, n))
print k
```

or

```
with open('file.txt') as w:
    k = np.asarray(w.readlines(),np.float)
    k = k[:,n]
```